# Where should "global" Symfony functions be placed?

Tags: php, symfony1

What's the best practice for placement of functions that are used across multiple MVC layers?

I've recently had to write some statistics functions that are used both in the View and the Model. If I put them in a helper, I'm stuck loading helpers in the model layer, which is annoying, seems incorrect, and breaks completely when those functions are called from a task (because there is no default context). If I put them in the top level `lib` directory, I'm stuck making calls like `Stats::normalPercentile` in the view.

Are there any other options? Are there any comments from Symfony devs on where functions like these should be placed?

**Edit**: Apparently there's no issue with making static calls in views. I inferred this based on Symfony not writing their helpers as classes (even after [significant discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/symfony-devs/browse_thread/thread/f20eb32c81439d60).) In that case, are there any conventions for placing files like these? Just throw them in `lib/util`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding your edit, symfony's helpers are written like that to avoid cluttering the view with syntax that might be unfamiliar to less technical folk who normally come into contact with a little PHP - functions being first-class citizens in 'vanilla' PHP. It's a philosophy drawn from Ruby on Rails, which inspired this part of the framework.

Storing files in `lib/` is a personal preference as symfony doesn't really mind, but the nomenclature would suggest `lib/vendor/yourname`.

If it's good code, you might want to guard it jealously in that little `yourname` directory... if it's *really* good code, you might want to [package it and share it with others](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/) :)

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with static calls? I think it's perfect for helper functions (better than functions as you have a kind of namespacing).

It's quite weird to gather stats in a view. Why don't you do it in an action?

Probably right answer depends on the kind of problem you're trying to solve (you didn't explain what exactly your helpers should do). I usually use such helpers for common tasks which don't require any additional classes or calls (like "stripText").

Comment: I agree: nothing wrong with static calls in the views. If the OP doesn't like it, he shall create a helper that masks them.

Comment: I'm not gathering stats in the view, but I am making calculations like the percentile of a value.

I guess I inferred (incorrectly) that static calls were frowned upon on the view because Symfony doesn't put their helpers inside of classes.

Answer (score 0):

Statistical calculations does not belong to the View. Consider adding them to the Model layer. The `lib/util` or `lib/model` seems both OK to me. For example you could have a class `PercentileSequence` which fed with data could be reused in both your views and tasks like this:

```
// in your action, component or task
$this->mySequence = new PercentileSequence($data);

// in your view (if PercentileSequence implements Iterator)
<?php foreach ( $mySequence as $rank ): ?>
    <?php echo $rank ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
// or use plain old array   
<?php foreach ( $mySequence->getRanks() as $rank ): ?>
    <?php echo $rank ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

It should be the same within a task.

Comment: Please do not debate the basis of the question. Can you conceive of a function that needs to be called both in a model and a view? Good. That is what I'm talking about here. Quibbling over whether *this specific instance* is one of them is detracting from my question.

Comment: Maybe this is why you are stuck with loading helpers in the Model layer or calling static methods :) Anyway, I voted your question up. I hope someone will come with a good answer.

Comment: My initial response was a little rude. This issue is a pet peeve of mine. Trust me that what I'm doing here is both appropriate and necessary :)